# Dipsplay title below video

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display the title below the video shown in the UI with its total length of the video like in YouTube videos. I have gone through many sites in google but not able to find answer for it.

```css
header {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 0px 6px 40px;
  height: 50px;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.divider {
  background-color: red;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<header>
  <h1> Main logo </h1>
  <nav>
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="divider"></div>

<video title="abcd" controls width="250" height="160"> ricemo
    <source  src="Thailand rice mill.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
<video title="asdf" controls width="250" height="160"> 
    <source src="China rice mill.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<figure>
  <video id="video_player" title="abcd" width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <figcaption id="meta"></figcaption>
</figure>

<script>
var myVideoPlayer = document.getElementById('video_player'),
    title = myVideoPlayer.getAttribute("title"),
    meta = document.getElementById('meta');

myVideoPlayer.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
    var duration = myVideoPlayer.duration;
    meta.innerHTML = "Duration is " + duration.toFixed(2) + " seconds and title is: " + title;
});
</script>
```

Edit:

```
var date = new Date(null);
date.setSeconds(SECONDS); // specify value for SECONDS here
var result = date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
```

Comment: Thanks it is working, if i have 3 videos in the folder and want to display the same name and length of the video below for all what changes should be made

Comment: You're welcome. You have 2 options: either hard-code everything or put it inside a loop. If this answer helped you, please choose it as [the correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to your question.

Comment: I will try putting a loop and get back to you if any doubts, one more thing how to convert the duration from seconds to minutes.

Comment: You can use the date function to format the time to anything, check my edit.

Comment: Corrected , i am trying to loop by giving only title at the center, i am able to get title only for one not for other video, can you please guide me how to correct it. please check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your browsers support video element and plugin available . This [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) may help you. For youtube video , you will need to use embed url like below my code and enjoy a bangla video song :)

```css
header {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 0px 6px 40px;
  height: 50px;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.divider {
  background-color: red;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<header>
  <h1> Main logo </h1>
  <nav>
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="divider"></div>

   

 <iframe width="250" height="160" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KTJELAZLh2M?ecver=2">
</iframe>
<figure>
  <video id="video_player" title="abcd" width="250" height="160" controls>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

</figure>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```